# CSS Fluid layouts

Tags: html, css, viewport, fluid-layout

I am designing a website using the CSS fluid layout (based on adaptive/responsive web design)

So I would not give anything as fixed value i.e. in px (only use %)

My question is ; While I do understand if I give the container a width of 100%, it would get calculated based on the browser window ( or viewport width) . But what about the font sizes like when we say 100% or 1 em for the body font, how will that be calculated ?
Also are the visible font-sizes going to be same on desktop as well as mobile devices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative font-size units are calculated from user default font-size, you have to use **media queries** if you want to adjust font-size from screen dimensions.

On mobile device text appears smaller because resolution is greater, be careful!

Comment: Ok..Let's say I only have the desktop...So how will it be calculated on the desktop ?

Comment: 1em = 1x user default font-size (usually 16px)

Comment: Right that is what i am looking for...So 16px equals 100% font size across all the browsers ?